# Find out location of OpenSSL and GnuPG using PHP?

Tags: php, webserver, openssl, gnupg

Is there a cross-platform compliant way of finding out the path to the main executables of OpenSSL and GnuPG? Obviously this would be `null` if the software was not installed or detected.

Answer (score 1):

You can explode `$_ENV['PATH']` by `PATH_SEPARATOR` and look for either `openssl` or `openssl.exe` (on Windows) in each of the paths (analogous for GunPG).

Comment: You mean explode by ; and not the PATH_SEPARATOR? My Windows install has OpenSSL installed as well as GnuPG, but I do not see a single path in the `$_ENV['PATH']` that would reveal it.

Comment: No, I mean what I said. `PATH_SEPARATOR` is `;` on Windows, but `:` on other platforms.

Comment: @rFactor If you don't see any path on the env variable that would reveal it, then all you can do is to scan the filesystem...